# SSH/Git: Specify paths with hostname instead of IP

Tags: ssh, git, hostname, clone

Alright, quick question.

When SSHing to a server using the IP, I can also specify a path to use, such as:

```
git clone ssh://git@127.0.0.1:/home/git/project.git SomeProject
```

However, when using a hostname, the command thinks the path is part of the host name:

```
git clone ssh://git@localhost.com:/home/git/project.git SomeProject
```

Which yields an error about the `:` before the path

> ssh: localhost.com:: no address associated with name

*(Yes, I am aware that I cannot SSH into localhost.com)*

Is there a way to specify the path as in the IP example, but with a hostname?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why did you decide that a Git SSH URI must have a `:` after a hostname? Where did you see this format?

Formal SSH-URI specification is

```
ssh://[user@]host.xz[:port]/path/to/repo.git/
```

Comment: It's derived from scp notation.

Comment: That is the strangest thing.... I seriously could not get it working until now. One of those days, I guess. Thanks!